# CSS one char per line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need all the text written in i a div to be vertical, like one character per line and centered.

The only way i've achieved is giving the div a fixed width of `width: 7%;` and a `word-break: break-all;`

Is there any way using CSS to achieve this with no fixed width?

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.flex-container > div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color : #62d962;
}

.flex-container > div:last-child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-container > div:last-child div {
    width: 7%;
}

.flex-container div:last-child div:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #65e9e3;
    word-break: break-all;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div>Box</div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Box</div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Box</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `width: 1ch`

Comment: And make sure to use monospace font because with a normal font two characters like "ll" may fit into one position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) and [`text-orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation) CSS properties, to achieve the
desired output.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.flex-container > div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color : #62d962;
}

.flex-container > div:last-child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-container > div:last-child div {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
}

.flex-container div:last-child div:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #65e9e3;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div>Box</div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Box</div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Box</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works! i've never used it before! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

css

```
#onechar {
    width: min-content;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="onechar">box</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).